# Change beans.xml according to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sessionfactory, xml-configuration

I created beans.xml for MySQL database. I added hibernate session factory and DB connection above xml file. But now I want to change my databases. New database is MongoDb. So How I change above xml file according to mongodb.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Session Factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.ongoingsolution.model.Test</value>
                <!--                <value>com.autosuport.modle.Customer</value>
                <value>com.autosuport.modle.Doneservices</value>
                <value>com.autosuport.modle.Donesuplire</value>
                <value>com.autosuport.modle.Login</value>-->               
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>               
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- dataSource configuration -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/autoservices" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

How to change above sessionfactory and new db connection in mongo databases.????